# Using the HTML::Element look_down method in Perl

Tags: perl, html-parsing

I need to parse a HTML file which is full of different type of `div` tags.

For example

```
<div class="..">
```

I think I have to use the `look_down` function, but don't know how to differentiate the mentioned `div` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about the [`HTML::Element`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aElement) module. `HTML::Element` objects are usually built by parsing an HTML document using [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder). Please read [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aElement): it is very well written.

You need to call the `look_down` method like this

```
my @divs = $doc->look_down(_tag => 'div', class => 'myclass');
```

where `myclass` should be replaced by the value of the `class` attribute that you want to select.

`@divs` will contain a list of `HTML::Element` objects that match those criteria.